# Set the screen resolution inside a xfvb wrap in a Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, xvfb, jenkins-2

In a Jenkins 2.0 pipeline, I'm using code similar to

```
wrap([$class: 'Xvfb']) {
  // execute selenium tests
}
```

As expected, this xvfb session uses the default screen resolution (1024x768x8?). I would like to override it.

According to the documentation at https://github.com/jenkinsci/xvfb-plugin, the Xvfb plugin has a Screen member that controls the resolution. What is the syntax for doing so? I've tried

```
wrap([$class: 'Xvfb'](Screen:'1440x900x24')) {
  // execute selenium tests
}

wrap([$class: 'Xvfb'][Screen:'1440x900x24']) {
  // execute selenium tests
}
```

and

```
wrap([$class: 'Xvfb']) {
  Screen = '1440x900x24'
  // execute selenium tests
}
```

Comment: try: `wrap([$class: 'Xvfb', screen: '1440x900x24']) { .. }`

Comment: @tim_yates: That did it. Write it up and I'll upvote your answer!

Comment: Done :-) glad it worked!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i believe config goes into the same map, so

```
wrap([$class: 'Xvfb', screen: '1440x900x24']) {
  // execute selenium tests
}
```

Should work. And you shouldn't need the square brackets either

Comment: How to wrap stages and steps?